# NodeJS looping through an array and prompt

Tags: arrays, node.js, sequence, prompt

I have an array of values to delete but want the user to confirm that he wants to delete the value. I plan to use the prompt Node module but don't know how to combine them in such a way that I move to the next value in the array after the user has confirmed (or not) the deletion of the current value. In short, the following code won't work:

```
        var arr = ["1","2","3"];
    for (var i in arr) {
      console.log("Delete " + arr[i] + "?");
      prompt.get(['response'], function (err, result) {
        console.log('  reponse: ' + result.response);
        // if ...
      });
    }
```

Any idea? Many thanks.

Comment: Is your project fully made with only nodeJS , or do you have some front end design with it , and js or js framework working with it ?

Comment: why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you're trying to use async calls `prompt.get` within syncronous loop `for`.
In case you have to make async calls you should to wait its callbacks. Particulary in your case you can use something like

```
function removeEl(idx, arr, done){
  if(idx>=arr.length) return done(arr);
  prompt.get(['response'], function (err, result) {
    console.log('  reponse: ' + result.response);
    if(/*user said yes*/){
      arr.splice(idx, 1);
      removeEl(idx, arr, done)
    }else{
      removeEl(idx+1,arr, done)
    }
  });
}

function removeWithPrompt(arr, done){
  removeEl(0, arr, done);
}

removeWithPrompt([1,2,3], function (modified) {
  // modified contains non-deleted elements
})
```

Or use asyncronous loops like [async.each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Answer (score 0):

@user1280859 is right about the issue but maybe it is better to take adventage of prompt features instead of recursion or asyncronous loop:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start();
var arr = ["1","2","3"];
var promptArr = arr.map(function(num) {
  return "Delete " + num + "?";
});

prompt.get(promptArr, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
      });
```

OutPut:

```
prompt: Delete 1?:  y
prompt: Delete 2?:  n
prompt: Delete 3?:  y
{ 'Delete 1?': 'y', 'Delete 2?': 'n', 'Delete 3?': 'y' }
```